# Performing matrix tensor product and getting a sum of its negative entries

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, variable-definitions, tensors, variable

I am given a $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$, which only has real entries.

Is there an efficient way to do the following two operations with $M$?

1. For a given input $n$, compute the $n$-fold tensor product $M^{\otimes n}$, without having to brute-force by manually using KroneckerProduct repeatedly (I want to handle large values of $n$ which makes manual calculation unwieldy).
2. For the matrix $M^{\otimes n}$, compute the total sum of all the negative entries.

Comment: What is a general way to do the tensor product --- something that is automated and not brute force?

Comment: Do you really need the tensor product -- or only the sum?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I needed both, but even the sum would be helpful. I could at least do the tensor product manually, by brute force, for a few small values of n.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think OP meant tensor product, not matrix product.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Indeed so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is only about the sums of negative entries, then yes.

This is how we can do it without even building the tensor/Kronecker products:

```
M = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
ClearAll[sumPositive];
ClearAll[sumNegative];
sumPositive[1] = Total[Ramp[ M], TensorRank[M]];
sumNegative[1] = Total[Ramp[-M], TensorRank[M]];
sumNegative[n_] := sumNegative[n] = Plus[
    sumPositive[n - 1] sumNegative[1],
    sumNegative[n - 1] sumPositive[1]
    ];
sumPositive[n_] := sumPositive[n] = Plus[
    sumPositive[n - 1] sumPositive[1],
    sumNegative[n - 1] sumNegative[1]
    ];
```

Test for `n = 8`:

```
n = 8;
result1 = sumNegative[n]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
result2 = Total[Ramp[-KroneckerProduct @@ ConstantArray[M, n]], 2]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

result1 == result2
```

> {0.00007, 4080}
>
> {1.63739, 688748008}
>
> True

Notice that `sumNegative[n]` needs $O(n)$ memory and FLOPs while the brute force approach needs $O(9^n)$ of both.

The key idea that the sum of all entries of a tensor product is just product of the sums:

```
Total[KroneckerProduct[A, A], 2] == Total[A, 2]^2
```

Now we only have onlt to keep track of the negative and the nonnegative parts of the tensors... Combined with recursion and memoization, we are lead to `sumPositive` and `sumNegative`.

## Remark

This can even be sped up by a clever decomposition of `n` into smaller parts and by exploiting that

```
sumNegative[m + n] == Plus[
  sumPositive[m] sumNegative[n],
  sumNegative[m] sumPositive[n]
  ]
sumPositive[m + n] == Plus[
  sumPositive[m] sumPositive[n],
  sumNegative[m] sumNegative[n]
  ]
```

So for a clever decomposition of your number $n$, you can compute the sum of all nonzero entries of $M^{\otimes n}$ in sublinear time. E.g., $n  = 2^k$ can be handled in $k = \log_2(k)$ time and memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Might you explain the code? How does it bypass computing the tensor product?

Comment: One specific question, what is the reasoning behind the Ramp function in Total[Ramp[M], 2]?

Comment: `Ramp` takes just the nonnegative part of all entries in the tensor (and zeroes the negative ones).

Comment: Will the same code work if $M$ is a $k \times k$ matrix (for a known $k$), instead of a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Well, you can try for yourself... But the answer is "yes". It should work for arbitrary tensors...